# How can I remove icecast2 competely

Tags: uninstall, purge

I installed icecast2 for broadcasting ( online radio). But complexity on its settings did suffered me. I want to remove it completely. I tried with `sudo apt-get purge icec*` system was start to delete unrelated files, and I stopped it with CTRL+C. So my Ubuntu desktop had gone and I reinstalled unity-2d again.
How can I remove this program and its plugins without affecting other programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is learning the hard way why it is potentially harmful to run commands recursively or with wildcards. This is especially true for commands we run as root.

Nevertheless we need to do so occasionally. Most of the time we will be warned if something bad may happen. This was also the case when you had purged packages using a wildcard `*` to remove all packages **and their dependencies** containing `icec*`. The system did tell you what it is going to remove, and it did ask you for confirmation `Y/n`:

```
[... long list of packages to remove]
After this operation, 978 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Whenecer you see a message like this, please **make a break**. Stop hitting keys, read the message and **think over it again**. Only if it seems exactly what you wanted you may press `Y`. In the case of purging `icec*` you will then be going to remove most of your system.

> To purge a package please use the complete package name rather than a wildcard abbreviation to make sure you will not remove any packages you may still need. If you do use wildcards please be extra careful.

The fastest and safest way to recover your system will now be to backaup your data and then reinstall Ubuntu (take care to not delete your `/home` directory).